# Getting values of multiple select inside one ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-ng-model

I have a dropdown in one of my div, from which I am selecting the number of dropdowns to be in second div. My task is to be able to select the different values from each of the dropdowns inside the second div. Here is the code I am trying

```
<div ng-repeat="i in getNumber(secondN2.core.r1r2.value) track by $index">
                <div>
                    <strong><u>For Core link number {{$index+1}}:</u> </strong><br>
                        <strong>Select IM</strong>
                        <select ng-model="im" ng-change="calculate()" >
                            <option value="1 Gig" selected="selected">1 Gig</option>
                            <option value="10 Gig">10 Gig</option>
                        </select><br>

                </div>

</div>
```

`secondN2.core.r1r2.value` is a number, I am converting it to array,a collection, by returning new Array(n), in the `getNumber` method

How to give the proper **ng-model** in this case? And how to retrieve the values?

If I try to give `i.im`, it still does not help. With `im`, `$scope.im` is coming `undefined`

**Updated**

What is two nested loops are there

```
<div ng-repeat="j in secondN3.core" style="border:1px solid;">
    <strong>Configure Core Links between {{j.name}}</strong><br><br>
            <div ng-repeat="i in getNumber(j.value) track by $index">
            <div>
                <strong><u>For Core link number {{$index+1}}:</u> </strong><br>
                <strong>Select IM</strong>
                <select ng-model="secondN3.coreValues[[$parent.$index,$index]]" ng-change="calculate()" >
                    <option value="1 Gig" selected="selected">1 Gig</option>
                    <option value="10 Gig">10 Gig</option>
                </select><br>
            </div>
        </div>
<div>
```

**Edit:2**

This is working: [This](http://plnkr.co/edit/byzgk2zR5dnlyAEMLhjh?p=preview) is the plunker for that

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could have an array in your controller that will hold the selected values:

```
$scope.values = [];
```

and then bind your dropdowns to this model:

```
<select ng-model="values[i]" ng-change="calculate()">
    <option value="1 Gig" selected="selected">1 Gig</option>
    <option value="10 Gig">10 Gig</option>
</select>
```

Comment: I did `ng-model="values[$index]"`, and now it is working :) Thanks